# What benefit do you get in javascript declaring an array with a specific length?

Tags: javascript

In most javascript apps I usually declare an array like so

```
var x = [];
```

but I've seen a ton of example code on MDN that take this approach instead

```
var x = new Array(10);
```

With V8/other modern JS engines, do you see a real benefit one way or the other?

Comment: Performance, though it's negligible.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246408/use-of-javascript-array-new-arrayn-declaration

Comment: `new Array(10);` Explicitly declaring with a length doesn't make any sense to me because there is no real length to an Array in JS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None. Javascript doesn’t implement real arrays. It all gets abstracted through javascript object notation.

So say:

```
a = [0, 1];
b = {"0": 1, "1": 1};
```

Has the same effect:

```
a[0] //0
b[0] //0
```

One more thing to keep in mind is when you do:

```
a[100] = 100;
```

The length gets automagically set to 101. Even though:

```
a[2] //undefined
```

Comment: I recall somebody demonstrating that some new engines take the size argument on faith and actually do some pre-allocation. It used to be the case that the array size was a *bad* idea, because if *really* old runtimes would blindly preallocate regardless of the value, leading to possible out-of-memory conditions.

Comment: It differs memory allocation wise. So it could matter depending on the scenario.