# ArrayList.ensureCapacity equivalent in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript

Is there an equivalent method in Javascript arrays or ArrayList to Java's ensureCapacity? I am translating a certain Java code containing this method to Javascript, and couldn't find any equivalent to it. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: No, there is no official one, but engines are pretty smart anyway. Some of them have an optimisation to pre-allocate memory when you assign a `.length`, but it doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to initialize an array with a specific size:

```
var array = new Array(n);
```

If your array has already been initialized you can, as mentioned in comments, set the length of the array using the `length` property:

```
array.length = n;
```

However, the performance gains, if any, seems negligble. [Here is a thread discussing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246408/use-of-javascript-array-new-arrayn-declaration).

Comment: And also set it via `array.length`

Comment: So, for instance, if I am using it this way:                  public Path(int initialCapacity)
   {
      
      tsIindexes.ensureCapacity(initialCapacity);
      tsJindexes.ensureCapacity(initialCapacity);

   }                                                                   would setting it with length amount to the same thing as done here?

Comment: Yeah, it would. But as mentioned, it is probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fruits = ['apple', 'pineapple'];
console.log(fruits.length, fruits);//2 ["apple", "pineapple"] 
fruits.length = fruits.length + 4; //increase by 4
console.log(fruits.length, fruits);//6 ["apple", "pineapple"]
```

```html
Open console for more ...
```