# How to properly declare a Javascript array of objects in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, declaration

I'm trying to create an object that contains an array of objects. I'm using a jquery selector to determine the number of objects I want in the array. I'm having some issue here because when I enter the for loop Firefox says that **"this.obj is undefined"** I tried both the the **this.obj = new Array()** syntax as well as the **this.obj[ ];** syntax.

```
function Base() {
    this.n = document.querySelectorAll('transform').length /3;
    this.obj = new Array(n); //array declaration
    for (var i = 0; i < this.n; i++) {
        this.obj[i] = new x3dSphere("b"+i); 
    }

}
```

I've only seen examples of arrays within objects that are declared like **this.obj = [1,2,2,4]** or the in the JSON form **obj: [1,2,3,4]**. I'm sure this is something really easy to do but I can't seem to find an example anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
function Base() {
    this.n = 5;
    this.obj = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.n; i++) {
        this.obj.push(new Test());
    }
}
```

Where `Test` was:

```
var Test = function () {};
```

It seems like the real problem is that it never created `this.obj` because `n` was undefined. If you want to declare the array how you did before, try `new Array(this.n)`.

**EDIT**

> Would new Array(this.n) be faster than the this.obj=[] syntax since it's pre-allocated?

Interestingly enough, [the answer is no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246408/use-of-javascript-array-new-arrayn-declaration).

Additionally, the accepted answer on this question has a great discussion of lots of other aspects of JavaScript array performance: [What is the performance of Objects/Arrays in JavaScript? (specifically for Google V8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423493/what-is-the-performance-of-objects-arrays-in-javascript-specifically-for-googl)

I've updated my answer to use `Array.push()` because it is apparently much, much faster than doing `Array[i] = new Obj()` (shout out to Jason, who used it in his original answer).

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me I always seem to forget "this". Would `new Array(this.n)` be faster than the `this.obj=[]` syntax since it's pre-allocated?

Comment: Answer is actually no, surprisingly. Updated my answer with that and a few other goodies.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare an array with

```
this.obj = [];
```

And then push objects into the array in a loop

```
for (var i =0; i < n; i ++) {
    this.obj.push(new x3dSphere ());
}
```